# Git workflow: "Your local changes would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git, github, merge

I've been working with another developer across three servers:

1. My local VM
2. Dev server
3. Live server

The workflow that I adopted was to, obiously, do all the work on my local VM, then pull the changes form the repomote repository to the dev server (dev branch) and live server (master beanch after merging with dev branch).

Unfortunately, another developer modified some files, install Wordpress plugins directly on the live server. Consequently, when I attempt to bring the `master` branch on the live server up to date with `master` on the remote reposiotry, I get messages like this one:

```
Error: Your local changes to 'plugins/bulk-page-creator/bulk-page-creator.php' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
```

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

I guess that these files are not tracked. I really want to avoid commiting to the remote repo from a server other than my local VM.

What are my opitons here to resolve this problem. I just need to bring the codebase on the live server up to date with the remote repo - that's it.

Should I somehow discard these local changes?

I also attempted to synchronize the codebase with:

`git fetch` 
`git merge FEATCH_HEAD`

with no luck.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you get that message because the files already exist locally, are not tracked in the currently checked out version, *and* the commit you are trying to merge in contains the file.

When Git already knows the file before the merge, then it can safely agree to overwrite it, but in this situation there is the chance that you have the file and don’t know that Git would now overwrite it, so Git simply won’t do it.

To resolve this issue, you just need to make room for Git to perform the merge. You can do this in two simple ways:

1. Delete the file. That way, Git will be able to check out the file from the new commit without any conflicts.
2. Rename the file. Same as above, but you have the chance to recover your local changes in case you want to make sure that everything you did locally is also included in the tracked file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a real multitude of these files. Would commiting them on the live server also help? I'm reluctant with messing with deletions as this is a live server and there shoudl not be a slightest diruption.

Comment: You could add and commit them but then you would have to deal with a merge and possible merge conflicts. If you just want to get rid of all possible local changes and get the remote version, you can also fetch the remote (`git fetch origin`) and then reset to its master using `git reset --hard origin/master`. But that will also make you loose anything, so make sure that you don’t have any actually needed changes left.

Comment: I opted for fetching and hard resetting to origin/master. All is good. Much appreciated!